# Navigating between two Visual Studio Solutions with F12

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to navigate between two Visual Studio Solutions?

For instance, I have two solutions: One with a various utility code and one comprising my actual app. When I hit F12 in the app solution, I am taken to a 'metadata' file, with function definitions only. Ideally, I would like to taken to the file in another instance of Visual Studio with the utility solution open.

Currently, I copy the thing I am seeking a definition on, then switch to the other instance of visual studio and conduct a search. Just curious if there's a faster way of doing this.

Comment: No can do.  The simple workaround is to add the projects your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I know. The only workaround that I know is to add the "utility" project(s) to your app solution. If you don't change them much VS won't try to recompile them all the time, and you'll have access to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Using [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and presumably a combination of the debug PDBs (generated with your Utility class build) then you're able to get right into the source of your libraries using F12 without needing to go to the other instance.